# Format decimal to store in a .txt

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to put a decimal number like `76,50` in a textbox. Add it like this in a listbox (that already works). I would save it to a .txt file, but when I open the .txt file I want the number to be like `07650` (only in the .txt file). When I open it back in my form it has to be `76,50` again. I already have the following in VB.net:

```
Public Function FormatDecimal(ByVal perc As Decimal, ByVal PercOut As Integer) As String
    Dim percent As Integer = 100
    Dim percAsString As String = perc.ToString("00000")`

    perc = perc * 100
    PercOut = Convert.ToInt32(perc)
    Do While txtPercentage.Text.Length < 5
        perc = 0 + PercOut
    Loop
    Return percAsString
End Function
```

I don't know where to put it; when I save the form to a .txt it stops.

I have been looking on the website for an answer but couldn't find one.  Can you help me?

Comment: The program just hangs where it's supposed to for example save the file to a .txt... No errors :-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop if the txtPercentage text is 6,50 you never exit

```
Do While txtPercentage.Text.Length < 5
    perc = 0 + PercOut
Loop
```

If your intention is just to have a decimal number with only two decimals formatted as a string in 5 characters without decimal separator then

```
Public Function FormatDecimal(ByVal perc As Decimal) As String
    Return (perc * 100).ToString("00000")
End Function
```

Comment: Okay but don't know how to solve it... If I enter 6,50 in the textbox and with a button(Add) add the value to a listbox it must be 6,50 in the listbox. If I save the records in the listbox to a .txt then the value must be changed to 00650. If I open the file back in the form and put the value back in the listbox it must be 6,50 again.

Comment: OOoow okay and then I should put it under the save and/or save as button??

Comment: It doesn't work... I just did a test. I think i'm doing something wrong :S

Comment: My listbox doesn't work anymore :D. I'll try to let it work again.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the "stupid" question. But my listbox works again, but can't get the value from the txtbox in the listbox. Now it gives "07650" in the listbox while it's supposed to be 76,50... Can you help me?

Comment: I can't give you an explanation of your problems without seeing the code that you use to put values in the Listbox or extract from it.

Comment: The code is a bit of a long one... Can you do something with the explanation in "How to save listbox items to notepad"?